# Changing Mono LRU Cache On Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono, monodevelop

I'm using mac + Mono installed to run MVC Web-based app.

When accessing some pages, it gives me:

> WARNING: WebConfigurationManager's LRUcache evictions count reached
>   its max size Cache Size: 100 (overridable via
>   MONO_ASPNET_WEBCONFIG_CACHESIZE)

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to increase the mono cache?

Comment: `overridable via MONO_ASPNET_WEBCONFIG_CACHESIZE`

Comment: @Gusman where can i find the setting? sorry i'm new here.

Comment: It's an environment variable.

Comment: ok thanks found it!